# Add additional permission on facebook application MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have a facebook application that is created in MVC. Now I want to add the following permissions on my application. publish_checkins, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_checkins. I don't really know where to place this additional permissions on my code. I might be thinking at this part.

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
```

I'm using the default permission that was provided when I created this app and followed the facebook birthday app tutorial. Another question, what if I already allowed the app from the previous permissions I have and now since I'm adding new ones, will the user be prompted to accept the new ones?

Any ideas guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you request permissions during the login process by using the `Login Dialog` and setting the `scope` option/parameter. If you need to request additional permissions after the user is logged in, you must invoke the Login Dialog again to request these additional permissions. Here's an extract from Facebook Developers documentation...

> During the basic login flow, your app receives access to a person's public profile and friend list. In order to access additional elements of their Facebook profile, or to publish content to Facebook on their behalf, you need to request permissions using the Login dialog. These permissions can be requested at the time of initial login or at any other point during the app experience.

You can find more info in the [Facebook Permissions Request Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

Comment: I have read the scope part where you list a comma separated scope object inside the login dialog. Can you give me an example?

Comment: how can I give you an example if I don't know how you are logging in your users? There's several ways you can login users. Can you update your question?